# I am using Gridsome and want a /image subfolder under src but this does not work

Tags: gridsome

I am using Gridsome found here...https://gridsome.org/docs/images/

I can display /src/image.png but /src/photos/image.png will not work. WHY is this?

How can I create a subfolder inside the src directory where I can keep all my images?